# Iteration through rows to uncapitalise strings words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know how to convert the first letter of each word in this column:

```
Test
There is a cat UNDER the table 
The pen is working WELL.
```

Into lower case, in order to have

```
Test
    there is a cat uNDER the table 
    the pen is working wELL.
```

For strings it would be ok to use the following code:

```
" ".join(i[0].lower()+i[1:] for i in line.split(" "))
```

How can I iterate this through rows in a column?

Comment: In regards to the deleted question, take a look at [Real Python: Practical Text Classification With Python and Keras](https://realpython.com/python-keras-text-classification/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a regex pattern and replacement lambda function. You can test the regex pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/MNOFlq/1):

```
df['Test'] = df['Test'].str.replace(r'((?<=\b)\S)', lambda x: x.group(1).lower())
```

Result:

```
                             Test
0  there is a cat uNDER the table
1        the pen is working wELL.
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import pandas as pd

def uncapitalise(x):
  words = x.split(' ')
  result = []
  for word in words:
    print(word)
    if word:
      word = word[0].lower() + word[1:]
    result.append(word)
  return ' '.join(result)

data = ['Test','There is a cat UNDER the table ','The pen is working WELL.']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[0] = df[0].apply(uncapitalise)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off your solution :

```
df["Test"] = [" ".join(entry[0].lower() + entry[1:] 
              for entry in word.split()) 
              for word in df.Test]


df

            Test
0   there is a cat uNDER the table
1   the pen is working wELL.
```